# G-WAN 7.12.2 segfault when not ran as a daemon

Tags: g-wan

I have ran a fresh install of latest G-Wan as *not* daemon (e.g. ./gwan).

I request some files (also tried nonexistant files) - all OK.

I request `/?` (no file name, just '?') and I get a `segfault` and server dies.

This is repeatable every time.

The above does not happen when in daemon mode.

Anyone experienced this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the same thing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/?
```

...and got *"The requested URL was not found on this server."* (as expected).

You might want to have a look at your `G-WAN handler` script, if any, which may not correctly handle this case.

As we updated the /include files per another question where you participated I suggest that you first download again the archive to update your include files.

The upated archive also includes the PH7 library and headers.